# COM Type hell. Ghost compiler re-writing my code?

Tags: winapi, com, atl

I've been working on a problem for over a week, so I may be blind, frustrated or just plain nuts. Please forgive me, but....

My class has this member:

```
IDevicePtr  devicePtr
```

a function wants `(IDevicePtr * ptr)` as a parameter.

I can't pass devicePtr to it, natural reasons:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'IDevicePtr' to 'IDevicePtr *
```

BUT...

i also can't pass &devicePtr to it:

```
compiler screams: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'IDevice **' to 'IDevicePtr *'
```

Where did "Idevice**" come from? How can I satisfy the "IDevicePtr *" function parameter requirements when I have an IDevicePtr object?

Sorry for the frustration. I've spent the last week trying to intercept one COM event without using ATL or MFC. No success. I haven't been able to locate a living person who ever did something like that.

Comment: What is the definition of IDevicePtr?

Comment: _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IDevice, __uuidof(IDevice));

Comment: are you using `#import`?

Comment: I am #import(ing) the *.TLB with those types. I am able to instantiate IDevicePtr objects and call methods on them. It's just this weird Ptr problem.

Comment: Should I import with #import "myCOM.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, no_namespace, named_guids? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` defines a pointer wrapper class - you can think of it as basically `typedef IDevice *IDevicePtr`, except that your `IDevicePtr` auto-releases and auto-references.

You should not be passing `IDevicePtr *`s around. Pass around `IDevice *` and wrap it in a `IDevicePtr` only if you take a reference, or pass a `IDevice **` if you want to return-by-reference (you can take the address of an `IDevicePtr` to get an `IDevice **`). Do not attempt to use a `IDevicePtr *` for return-by-reference; this will fail (this is the problem you are seeing) because of that `operator&` overload.

Comment: so, you're saying a reference (&) to an instance of this macro defined wrapped class cannot exist in C++? I am not sure why a &myWrapperInstance can't work?

Comment: @RM1970 the smart pointer class overloads `operator&` to return an `IDevice **`; this allows you to use these smart pointers with ordinary COM functions that do return-by-reference